# Telerik mvc grid paging/sorting/filtering calling controller action method why

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik

Telerik mvc grid paging/sorting/filtering calling controller action method why.how to prevent to call a controller action method and perform paging/sorting successfully.please eleborate this and explain the solution for this..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you do not want to POST back to the controller when you page, sort, or filter. This can be achieved by setting the OperationMode property to Client, making all of these actions occur on the client-side. A demo of this, including code, can be [seen here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/operationmode).

One thing to keep in mind is that this means that all of the data is loaded to the Grid on initial page load, so depending on the data and browsers you are dealing with you might want to instead load data as needed, which can be done via [Ajax binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/ajaxbinding).